# Configure launch.json and tasks.json to debug different C# projects in Vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, debugging

I just started learning how to use C# in Vscode but cannot generate Json files to debug diferent projects in a solution.

For context I have two projects, Test01 and Test02. The Json files look like this:

Launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
            // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
            // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Test01/bin/Debug/net7.0/Test01.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Test01",
            // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Test01/Test01.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Test01/Test01.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "--project",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Test01/Test01.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm triyng to configure vscode to start learning C# using Vscode solution explorer extension to add multiple projects in the same solution but when i generate the launch.json and tasks.json files they only add the path to one of the projects. Should I create multiple launch/tanks configurations (one for each project) or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply duplicate the existing configurations and tasks within their respective files.

Launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Test01",
        ...
        "preLaunchTask": "build Test01", 
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Test01/bin/Debug/net7.0/Test01.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Test01",
        ...
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Test02",
        ...
        "preLaunchTask": "build Test02", //match the tasks name from Tasks.json
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Test02/bin/Debug/net7.0/Test02.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Test02",
        ...
    }
    ...
]
}
```

Tasks.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build Test01",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "process",
        "args": [
            "build",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Test01/Test01.csproj",
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
        "label": "build Test02",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "process",
        "args": [
            "build",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Test02/Test02.csproj",
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    ...
]
}
```